# How do I get dataset to align with shapefile using leaftlet?

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping

I want to make a map using my data called jb. I can say that a few of the districts in my districts variable in my dataset and the shapefile match. Rest are "FLASE" because the complete districts in the shapefile do not exist in my dataset because I did not get responses from those districts.I hope was that if I went to regardless, those district that did not match would be assigned "not enough information".

I went on regardless.

this is my dataset of 6 districts, my shapefile has 150 districts:

```
          Districts  totalrespond totalcont      per.content
1               1          4         2                 50            
2               2          2         0                 0           
3               3          1         0                 0 
4               4          1         0                 0 
5               5          2         0                 0
```

I put this code:

```
bins <- c(0,5,10,30,40,50,60)
pal<-colorBin("RdYlBu",domain=jb$per.content, bins=bins)


m<- leaflet() %>%
   setView(-96,37,4) %>%
   addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner)%>%
   addPolygons(data =districts.th,
               weight = 1,
               smoothFactor = 0.5,
               color = "white",
               fillOpacity = 0.8,
               fillColor= ~pal(fb$per.content))
m
```

I only got the openstreet map with no color layer I was expecting from the districts. I was expecting a colored layer on the map. I am not sure if it due to the lack of districts matching or something else.

Comment: You specified the domain as `jb$per.content`, but you have `fb$per.content` in `addPolygons`. I wonder if this is doing something.

Comment: It is posible that your shapefiles are not in the same proyection as leaflet map, which is in lon-lat porjection.

Comment: Use this funtion call before running your code and let me know.  disctirct <- sp::spTransform(district, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

Comment: Hi Johan, something happen. The values showed up on map, but the districts boarder line in the country country. do you know why that may be?

Comment: I can't tell. You are not showing any information about your shapefiles, my last comment was a lucky shot based on my experience.

Comment: I don't even know the country we are talking about. I am from Dominican Republic, for example :)